# You can't specify target table 'table_name' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I begined read more in-depth MySql and try solved this task on [description](https://leetcode.com/problems/delete-duplicate-emails/description/). According to description need delete a duplicats from table, but my query not work. In sqllite is work fine. What is the reason?

```
DELETE
FROM
    Person
WHERE
    Email IN(
    SELECT
        Email
    FROM
        Person
    GROUP BY
        Email
    HAVING
        COUNT(Email) > 1
);
```

error

```
You can't specify target table 'Person' for update in FROM clause
```

Comment: you didn't specify which duplicate you want to delete of course there is an error

Comment: Do you really want to remove both rows if there are duplicates? (Instead of keeping one of them.)

Comment: Table to be updated, `Person`, is also used to determine which rows to update (actually delete in this case). MySQL doesn't permit this. You can work around it using a nested subquery (the method is explained in the duplicate reference link)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a self join to delete duplicates

```
delete a
from Person a
left join Person b on a.Email = b.Email
                 and a.id > b.id
where b.Email is not null
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/KJYDWH70372)

```
+----+------------------+
| Id | Email            |
+----+------------------+
| 1  | john@example.com |
| 2  | bob@example.com  |
+----+------------------+
```

Comment: Where does it come from? Person a and Person b

Comment: Its a self join , mean join with itself and aliased as a and b